# How to calculate current in a symmetric circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-design

[image]

I am relatively new to circuit diagram and I am trying to find out how I can calculate Io shown in the above diagram. From my understanding, this looks like a symmetric circuit diagram, however I can't wrap my head around it on how to calculate the current on that point.

Comment: well you can easily solve it with Kirchhoff Voltage Law and combine it with the current law in each node should lead you to the solution. There is a policy about questions that seem from homework so try to show some work

Comment: You have components connected by *Nodes*. A node is a set of component connections that have equal voltage. The long line at the top connecting 4 resistors is a node. The point connecting the 12V+ terminal to two resistors is another node. Try redrawing it so the voltages decrease down the page. Draw the power supply nodes as long lines, one at the top of the page, one at the bottom, and string the resistors out between them, keeping their topology. That might help hint at how to combine them.

Comment: Roy, it is symmetrical. By inspection you can see that the top wire and the bottom wire must be at the same voltage, which should mean something to you regarding the two \$12\:\Omega\$ resistors and their currents. Once you see that much, the rest is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

redraw like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkuOHx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>